# passing argument 1 of 'strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast + Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, if-statement, c-strings, string-literals

C newbie here, I can't figure out what's wrong with my code please help me out.
I get two warnings, one on line 12 and the other on line 15.

Line 12 : Comparison between pointer and integer

Line 15: passing argument 1 of 'strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = {"<h1>heading 1</h1>"};
    char string_len = strlen(string);
    char new_string;

    for (int i = 0; i < string_len; i++) {
        if (string[i] !="<" || string[i] !="/" || string[i] !=">") {
            strcat(new_string, string[i]);
        }      
    }

    printf(new_string);

    return 0;
}
```

I am actually trying to code a simple HTML Parser, but stuck on the beginning.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ if you are writing and asking about C code.

Comment: Characters are in single quotes: `'<' et. al. You cannot compare character to cstring using operators, you likely want to compare characters (e.g. `string[i] != '<'`).

Comment: Declaring a `char` variable named `new_string` suggests a mistake is being made. As well as using `char` rather than `size_t` for the length of a string.

Comment: `"<"` has type `char const[2]`, since it's a string literal. The expression `string[i]` has type `char&`...

Comment: `char[2]` and `char` respectively, actually

Comment: You need to study strings before using them. These are all trivial mistakes best answered by the string chapter in your favourite C book. Contrary to popular belief, SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial to replace conventional studies.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `new_string` has the type `char`

```
char new_string;
```

It can store only one character.

So the call of `strcat`

```
strcat(new_string, string[i]);
```

does not make a sense. The both arguments have the type `char` while the function expects arguments of the type `char *` that point to strings.

You need to declare a character array.

And if you will declare an array then to use this call

```
printf(new_string);
```

the array must contain a string. Moreover instead of using this call of `printf` it is better to write either

```
printf( "%s\n",new_string);
```

or

```
puts(new_string);
```

In this if statement you are comparing characters with string literals that used in the expression are converted to pointers.

```
if (string[i] !="<" || string[i] !="/" || string[i] !=">") {
```

You need to use integer character constants instead of the string literals

```
if (string[i] !='<' || string[i] !='/' || string[i] !='>') {
```

And instead of the logical OR operator you need to use the logical AND operator

```
if (string[i] !='<' && string[i] !='/' && string[i] !='>') {
```